# how to calculate comedian(c) in matlab?

Tags: matlab

i have a x=(t*n) stock return matrix, that n is number of stock in a portfolio and t is time. i want calculate c=M{[x(it)-k(x)][y(it)-k(y)]}where x(it) return of stock i in time t and  the median M is taken with respect to the joint CDF of x(t) and y(t), and k(x) and k(y) are the population medians of x(t) and y(t).

Comment: CAN YOU SHOW US WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED SO FAR? ALSO, HOW DID YOU GO FROM `X` TO THE NEW MATRIX?

Comment: @rayryeng stop yelling, you're hurting my ears

Comment: @ballBreaker WHAT DID YOU SAY?

Comment: Please look over the question and try to put the requirement in simple english that others can understand

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer but honestly I wrote it based on the last version of your question. I think you should roll back your edit to this version (_version 6_), because in it's current state I would have been unable to answer it. The effort to explain the problem better is appreciable, but you should at least leave the numerical example ...

Comment: @Hoki thank you for good answer to my last version of my question and i'm sorry for changing it. I try put a numerical example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer (because you finally explained a workable example input=>desired output) before closing the question.

```
x = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9] ;
T = size(x,1) ; N = size(x,2) ;

R = [x,x(:,1)] ;                % copy the first column in last position (to be able to loop seamlessly)
for k=1:N
    R(:,k) = R(:,k).*R(:,k+1) ; % multiply columns element wise
end
R(:,end) = []                   % remove the last column

R =
     2     6     3
    20    30    24
    56    72    63
```

---

I suggest you read about indexing in MATLAB [on Mathworks site](http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html)